# How to convert a DataFrame with String into a DataFrame with Vectors in Scala(Spark 2.0)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DataFrame with a column named *KFA* containing a string with angular braces on both ends. There are 4 double values in this long string. I would like to convert this into a DataFrame with vectors.

This is the first element of the DataFrame:

```
> dataFrame1.first()
res130: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [[.00663 .00197 .29809 .0034]]
```

Could you help me to covert it into a dense vector with 4 double values.

I have tried this command

```
dataFrame1.select("KFA")
    .map((x=>x.mkString("").replace("]","").replace("[","").split(" ")))
    .rdd.map(x=>Vectors.dense(x(0).toDouble,x(1).toDouble,x(2).toDouble,x(3).toDouble,x(4).toDouble))
```

This looks very clumsy and unreadable. Could you suggest any other ways of doing this?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `mkString` if you are just going to split it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Used `mkString` because I couldn't use `.replace("]","")` on a spark.sql.Row

Comment: You don't need to create a string, I don't think. You can `getAs[Double]` from a Row object

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with Regular expression:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

val p = "[.0-9]+".r 
val rddVec = dataFrame1.select("KFA")
             .map(x => Vectors.dense(p.findAllIn(x(0).toString).map(_.toDouble).toArray))

# rddVec: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MapPartitionsRDD[49] at map at <console>:39

rddVec.collect
# res43: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = 
         Array([0.00663,0.00197,0.29809,0.0034], [0.00663,0.00197,0.29809,0.0034])
```